# Facebook Insight - how to get insight with app_id for directories or pages within a domain

Tags: facebook, app-id

Putting the meta properties tags

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1020xxxx" />
```

in the root of the domain, I was able to see insights and then further check the insights on a page by page basis (mySite/index and could check mySite/otherPage).

The problem with this is I wanted others to be able to view these insight and that requires me to add more fb:admin metatags with this approach. I've tried instead to use an app_id since you can assign roles and manage who has access with this tag

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="70181784xxxx" />
```

but I don't see a way to get insights at a page level.
Correct me if I'm wrong, but I can only use one app_id a domain (with the app_id being at the root page since otherwise I get the error when trying to get insights). The app_id just gets the insights of everything at that domain (including its directories). Putting an app_id on a specific page doesn't do anything.

I also looked into Page IDs but they seem to be specifically for facebook's own pages and not to get insights for separate web pages (unless I am missing something here as well).

So to restate my question clearly: Is there a way to get facebook insights for separate pages that also allows for dynamic adding/editing of roles? I do not want to keep managing who is in charge of this if the development or client change personnel.

I've attached an image showing what I'd like an equivalent of functionality-wise.
[Problem Pic](http://i44.tinypic.com/2qmkzza.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

So from what I've gathered,

My attempt to use an app to get pages isn't possible since an app for facebook isn't a website per-say and thus can't divide its data into pages.

I also assume the website insight is just less of a priority for facebook than dedicated facebook apps so they are not going to retrofit the concept of different roles to it.